# How to load all remaining content of a view after clicking a "load more" link?

Tags: 7, views, javascript

I have a view block that list contents.

What I want to do is to show only 5 items in this view and a `load more` link at the bottom of the view and if this link clicked, then show **all remaining** content of the view.

I tried the [Views Load More](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_load_more) module and the [Views Infinite Scroll](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll) module. The Views Load More module didn't work, the Views Infinite Scroll module works good but I couldn't do what I want. It has an option to show X items per "show more" link clicked but it doesn't have an option to show all the remaining content of the view.

**How to load all remaining content of a view after clicking a "load more" link?**

[image]

Comment: I hesitate to post this as an answer (I might, if it makes sense ...): (1) clone that views block in a new views block that shows all content (2) adapt your views block to only show 5 items, and in its footer add a link with title "show more", which links to the same path, but with (say) "show_more" added to it. Then use block visibility settings to only show either block on relevant paths (pages). Makes sense? Or not at all?

Comment: Thanks @Pierre.Vriens for your answer :) Hımm, I want to do this without refreshing/redirecting the page. I will try your solution if I can't find a "better" way. Thanks again.

Comment: It's a "*comment*" only (not an "*answer*") ... Ping me about it if you ever want me to convert it to an answer anyway. I'm also curious for "other" answers ... Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [Views show more](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_show_more) module with ajax under views advanced setting. This module provides Initial item selection option, and rest of the item you can put in the section of on-click.

**Steps-**

1. Download and enable the module.
2. Select **show more pager** in the Pager section as shown in the image. Then go for setting for that. Now in my case I took 15 items, and I want to initially show 5 items and on clicking rest of the item. So I did put 5 under the **Initial items** and 10 items under **Items to display** as shown in second image. And under Animation section select **Scroll to new content.** Save this, so pager setting ends here.
3. Under advanced setting of views enable, **Use Ajax: Yes**

**Views Block UI**
[image: Views UI]

**Pager UI**

[image: Pager UI]

**Out put image:**

**Initial stage**

[image]

**After clicking show more**

[image]

It does not require the page refresh to load content.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It does what I exactly need. I'm using the EVA module and at first it doesn't work then I found that (https://www.drupal.org/node/2672220) and then it worked.